# Why does, when opening certain websites, text appears to load after all the graphics?

Tags: website

https://blog.twitter.com/2010/introducing-open-source-twitter-text-libraries

It's not really noticeable if you have a high-speed low-latency connection, but after many tries, I snapped a screenshot that displays the problem

[image: half loaded website]

Comment: Are you asking for an answer or an explanation?

Comment: @chipperyman573 explanation (..as to why does this happen? which would be an answer I thought??).